# Ordering numbers from a file, split in two rows

Tags: java, file

I have a file, created with an algorithm in Java that is written in this way:

```
3.03 1.08
2.02 4.07
1.04 2.010
4.02 2.09
6.02 3.57
5.03 4.00
7.06 2.012
8.07 2.145
9.10 2.04
10.11 2.02
```

Basically there are 2 numbers for each row, separated by a space. Is it possible to read this file and order in a descending order for the second row? In that way that the result is this:

```
2.02 4.07
5.03 4.00
6.02 3.57
8.07 2.145
4.02 2.09
9.10 2.04
10.11 2.02
7.06 2.012
1.04 2.01
3.03 1.08
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And what have you tried so far? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: if you use unix try the sort command (`man sort`). It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a class `Data` that has 2 `Double attributes` with a `Comparable` that **Overriding** `compareTo` Method which will sort `Data` in descending order depends on **SecondNumber** value.

```
class Data implements Comparable<Data> {
    double FirstNumber;
    double SecondNumber;

    public Data( double FirstNumber, double SecondNumber) {
        this.FirstNumber = FirstNumber;
        this.SecondNumber = SecondNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data o) {
        if (this.SecondNumber < o.SecondNumber) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

In this `main` method i have created an **array** of `Data` populated with data provided in your question. And in order to **call** the **compareTo** method, simply call `java.util.Arrays.sort(map);` that will implicitly call the **compareTo** method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Data[] map = new Data[10];
        map[0] = new Data(3.03,1.08);
        map[1] = new Data(2.02,4.07);
        map[2] = new Data(1.04,2.010);
        map[3] = new Data(4.02, 2.09);
        map[4] = new Data(6.02,3.57);
        map[5] = new Data(5.03,4.00);
        map[6] = new Data(7.06,2.012);
        map[7] = new Data(8.07,2.145);
        map[8] = new Data(9.10,2.04);
        map[9] = new Data(10.11,2.02);

        java.util.Arrays.sort(map);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(map[i].FirstNumber +" "+ map[i].SecondNumber);
        }
    }
```

**The result would be :**

```
2.02 4.07
5.03 4.0
6.02 3.57
8.07 2.145
4.02 2.09
9.1 2.04
10.11 2.02
7.06 2.012
1.04 2.01
3.03 1.08
```